# Can appcelerator create Android-Auto compliant apps?

Tags: appcelerator, android-auto

I'm new in Android Auto, but I developed a lot of apps using Appcelerator. My question is: is it possible to integrate Android Auto in an app of mine created using appcelerator?
I know that in order to implement Android Auto services using Android Studio you need to put some code in the manifest xml of your app, implement some services and so on (as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/), but I don't know if it's possible (and how) to do the same using Appcelerator.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: It would be better if u ask this question in the slack team ti-slack

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know this team, but I'll take a look!

Comment: @TheFuquan I disagree that users should be automatically be redirected to ti-slack since because it's a closed chat-like service, the information is not archived and later searchable by people who might be looking for the same kind of information, and those making users need to ask the same set of questions again. SO if a perfect place to ask questions and a great tool where developers can learn from previous asked questions and answers.

Comment: @developer82 i m with you on this one, especially since like you ve stressed, with slack you loose history and even so, their search engin ain’t that powerful.... this said, ive seen all ti developers move to that team so new comers are left alone on SO, I just suggested tislack for this person to get help, I’ll add this we have a channel called helpthem that concerns all loner developers in the wild like stackoverflow  or others

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting question and research to do. From what I've read in the link you have provided the Android-Auto is a regular android application. So theoretically it should be possible, since a Titanium app itself is an Android application, and the android manifest is available to you in `tiapp.xml`

What I would do to test it is:

- First of all target SDK 21 or above (as stated on the page).
- AFAIK v4 support library should already be included in a Titanium app, but if it's not you could easily include it.
- "Define the Auto XML configuration file" - easily supported by Titanium apps in the `resources` directory.
- Add a manifest entry - As mentioned above, the android manifest is available to you in  `tiapp.xml`.

For the rest of the instructions, if UI development is involved you could check if Titanium way of building UI works here, if not you could always include them as XML layout files (that's the great thing about Titanium), or even create a module with your own custom activity.

Just make sure to follow the design guidelines by google as they are very strict.